How to return two values in C within a function with pointers?
I was trying to learn pointers and implement them into a card game. I was trying to get my deal function to return two card numbers, how could I do that with pointers? (I know I can use a struct, but just wanted to learn pointers).
void deal()
{
    srand (time (0));
    int card1 = (rand() % 13) + 1;
    int card2 = (rand() % 13) + 1;  
    return card1, card2;
}

Ive tried using a struct and it worked, but I just wanted to learn more about pointers and how to use them.

To "return" multiple values there are mainly two solutions: Pointer to variables, passed as arguments using the pointer-to operator &; Or returning a structure.

Please do not post code as image. Post it as text, using the appropriate formatting.

On a different note, don't call srand more that once in your program. For most PC systems, the time function have second resolution, which means if deal is called twice in the same second, the same seed would be used, and you would get the exact same numbers.

As a solution for your case, why not a single function that gets the random number, and then call it twice to get the two values? Like int card1 = random_card(); int card2 = random_card();? There's just no need to "return" multiple values for your use-case.

The comma is a sequence point in return card1, card2;. It is short for card1; return card2;, (it doesn't do anything with card1.)

see srand() — why call it only once?. Calling srand in your function is a very bad idea because it'll be called every time your function is called. Also see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

You cannot return two values from a function. You can dereference pointers passed to your function and assign.
void f(int *a, double *b) {
    *a = 42;
    *b = 27.3;
}

int main(void) {
    int x;
    double y;

    f(&x, &y);

    // ...
}

Be sure you pass in the address(es) of valid memory. You might be tempted to write:
void f(int *a, double *b) {
    *a = 42;
    *b = 27.3;
}

int main(void) {
    int *x;
    double *y;

    f(x, y);

    // ...
}

But in this case, x and y are pointers, so the code compiles, but they're uninitialized, and so do not (or may not) point to valid memory locations that can hold an int and a double respectively.
Dereferencing these in the function f therefore has indeterminate behavior. It may "work" or it may crash, or something else may happen.
To avoid situations like this, compile with warnings on.
A sidenote on dealing cards
On a sidenote, this is not how dealing out two cards works. With a finite deck, you cannot deal the same card twice. But your code allows that to happen. Rather you want to create a deck, shuffle it, and then access the "top" two elements.
A trivial example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void shuffle(int *arr, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int rand_idx = rand() % (n - i) + i;

        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[rand_idx];
        arr[rand_idx] = temp;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    shuffle(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr));
    printf("%d, %d\n", arr[0], arr[1]);
}


These are commonly called out-parameters.

You could also make a trivial struct and return that by value, or pass in a struct by pointer to make changes to that.

@tadman absolutely, but the OP mentioned already doing that successfully.

Good options: Pass and receive values by pointer. Either individual cards or a struct.
void deal2(card *card1, card *card2) {
   *card1 = deal();
   *card2 = deal();
}

void deal2(struct cards *cards) {
   cards->card1 = deal();
   cards->card2 = deal();
}

A common pattern in C is to pass (usually as the first parameter) the memory address in which you wish to store your result.
OK Option: Allocate and return a pointer
struct cards *deal2() {
   struct cards *cards = malloc(sizeof struct cards);
   cards->card1 = deal();
   cards->card2 = deal();
   return cards;
}

This isn't wrong, but each call allocates memory and you must remember to deallocate it. It's slightly less flexible than the first option. In the first case, you can use the same memory address multiple times, and each call will overwrite it.
Bad option:
struct cards deal2() {
   struct cards cards;
   cards.card1 = deal();
   cards.card2 = deal();
   return cards;
}

This returns a copy of the struct, which is a slow process and takes up a lot of stack. It might be fine for one or two calls, but it's a bad general solution.
Incorrect option:
struct cards *deal2() {
   struct cards cards;
   cards.card1 = deal();
   cards.card2 = deal();
   return &cards;
}

This returns a pointer to the stack, which means it will get overwritten whenever another function is called.

Your second to last example assumes that the members of a struct cards value are in turn of type struct cards. This isn't only a bad example, but definitely incorrect.

In your first two examples, how can you assign to a variable the result of a void function?

Oops, you're right, I should have called it deal2

@Chris feel free to take another look.

In those first few examples, how are you now defining deal? You also reference copying structs by value as a bad option, but if they're trivial (e.g. struct cards { int card1; int card2; }; then worrying about this is definitely over-optimizing. Passing around a pointer probably consumes as much stack space.

"how are you now defining deal"
Left as an exercise to the reader.
"if they're trivial" Yes, in this individual case. Most of the time structs aren't trivial.
